# Ignoring a category in WP_Query still shows the links in next_post_link()?

Tags: categories, wp-query

So I have a WP_Query like so:

```
$homepage = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&cat=-5' );
```

and in my while loop, I have a call to `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()`, which are both showing posts from the excluded category. Here is what my code looks like next:

```
<?php while ( $homepage->have_posts() ) : $homepage->the_post(); ?>
 <?php next_post_link('&laquo; %link'); ?> 
 <?php previous_post_link('%link &raquo;'); ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

According to [the wordpress docs on next_posts_link & previous_posts_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link), these functions are based on the current query:

> Prints a link to the next set of posts within the current query.

So does anybody have an idea of why `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` would show posts that should be excluded while the rest of the loop works as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to exclude the category in your `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` calls too, as it's using the posts data, not your specific queries data, so, this should fix it:

```
while ( $homepage->have_posts() ) : $homepage->the_post(); 
    next_post_link( '&laquo; %link', '%title', false, '5' );  
    previous_post_link( '%link &raquo;', '%title', false, '5' );  
endwhile;
```

Where 5 is the excluded category. If you need to exclude more categories, just comma separate them.

Comment: Sadly, they are both still displaying posts from category 5.

Comment: Now in my specific setup, setting that `false` to `true` cleared up the issues because of how my categories were set up, thanks still!